# Медиа запросы и масштаб в браузере

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть

```
<div style="width:1366px; height:500px">
```

Можно ли менять его свойства, в зависимости от масштаба в браузере, допустим при 125% ширина будет равна 700px, а при 150% ширина равна 500px.
В медиа запросах как я понял можно делать зависимости от размера экрана, можно ли делать зависимость от масштаба браузера?

Comment: эти понятия относительные, меняя масштаб в браузере ты отлавливаешь параметры монитора больше(у тебя 1366х768, а отдалив допустим станет 1920х1080) потому все возможно, только не по 150% - 125%

Comment: В css есть `device-pixel-ratio`. Насколько помню, оно при изменении масштаба меняется

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `width` и `height` страницы автоматические меняются в зависимости от zoom-а. Поэтому, нет смысла отталкиваться от zoom-а.

Чтобы проверить как это работает, откройте http://mediaqueriestest.com/, поиграйтесь с zoom-ом и посмотрите, как меняются параметры `width` и `height`. Зато неизменными остаются `device-width in px` и `device-height in px`
И ещё, чтобы "перезаписать" css, свойства которого прописаны в атрибуте `style` внутри тэга, необходимо добавить `!important`: `div{width: 500px !important}`